# Remove Page From Multipage TIFFs In Matlab

Tags: matlab, tiff, libtiff

I have tiff files where I want to remove the even numbered pages. I have read other posts asking for the method in many different languages except for Matlab. How can this be done in Matlab?

Comment: Too broad. Just look at the docs for [reading a page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#inputarg_idx) and [writing multiple pages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#input_argument_namevalue_writemode)

Comment: I did take a look at them but didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for your problem is to read only the relevant tiff pages (i.e. the odd ones) and the save them in a separate file. This can be done as follows:

```
%defines path to input and output files
inputFileName = '<input file name>';
outFileName = 'out.tiff';

%reads tiff file info
tiffData= imfinfo(inputFileName);

%reads every odd page and append it to the output file
for k = 1:2:numel(tiffData)
currentTiff = imread(inputFileName,k);
imwrite(currentTiff, outFileName, 'writemode', 'append');
end
```

Comment: @Senyokbalgul This does save the output file... `'out.tiff'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to save the output file?

Comment: @Suever Actually the code above saved it, thanks though. Although, is there a way to save the output file to a different folder than the input folder?

Comment: Sure, use the full path for the output file name. For example, if you want the output file to be located at C:\newDirectory,
simply write: outFileName = 'C:\newDirectory\out.tiff';

Comment: @ everyone Thanks a lot guys